# How disable redirection when add item to cart with SyliusCartBundle in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm already implement the basic of SyliusCartBundle (http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html)

but the problem is the method to add item to a cart, because the only way that I know is with

```
<a href="{{ path('sylius_cart_item_add', {'productId': product.id}) }}">Add product to cart</a>
```

acording to http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/actions.html

and I want to add a item without redirect the webpage.

sorry if is too basic but I only start with symfony 4 day ago.

Comment: Maybe `ajax` will solve your problem

Comment: maybe but I'm looking for something in php. Some like:

    addToCart($item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @zizoujal say is with ajax. But when I ask I was a beginner in MVC and I dont undestand the method.

The solution is:

1. Create an action that get de information of the cart and only save it, return an json respoonse like {result: success}.
2. in the view call with ajax this action and if return result== success do the action you want.

Finally I dont use Symfony2 (SyliusCartBundle) but with a little more experience in MCV I can undestand and I implment my own action (in cakephp).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it but it may help you:

- Write your own controller, use yourbundle_cart_item_add and add the respective routings.
- Imitate what it is done in the `Sylius/Bundle/CartBundle/Controller/CartItemController:addAction`.
- At the end, instead of redirectToCarSummary() redirect to what you want.

Comment: I changed Symfony2 with cakephp because I found a easily implementation of cart shopping in cakephp.